# QtableWidget date field not showing up correctly? QtCore to Python data type conversion?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, type-conversion

I'm filling a QTableWidget with data that I read from a QDialog.
The data is all sorts; dates, bools, ints, mostly strings.

I do the following lines of codes for every value I need to insert into the table:

```
val = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(val))

self.tableWidget.setItem(len(myList), index, val)
```

This works fine except in the date field of the table I get the following:

```
PySide.QtCore.QDate(2013, 7, 7)
```

I tried to convert the date to a string using:

```
d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

The following error shows up:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtCore.QDate' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

This leads me to believe all the data I read from the form was in QtCore data types.
I read somewhere that PySide implicitly converts to Python data types, but obviously I'm wrong.

So,
1. how would I solve the issue stated above?
2. do I need to need to explicitly convert all the data to Python types, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `QDate` type, refer to `QDate`'s documentation. You can convert it to string using [QDate::toString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#toString).

Comment: But are all of my data types of QtCore?